# Parsing HTML document to get certain Text Data

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm building a web crawler which uses JSoup for parsing the HTML Document. Currently I'm using the ***getElementById()*** and the ***text()*** methods to get the text for 3 or 4 fields. But it seems to me that every time the HTML structure changes, I'll need to change my code to adapt to it.

Is there a better and more robust way to get the required fields?

Comment: This is a bit broad. You need to analyse the page you are parsing and identify the stable parts and build your scraper accordingly. Learn to use the JSoup CSS selector syntax for grabbing the content: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: You cannot create a universal template to crawl different sites rather you can create template to crawl very basic standard information like meta content,title,description.